# python using ord() with getch() to get unicode

Tags: python, keyboard-events, getch

i am learning python at the moment and i tried to get keyboard input, without the need to press the enter key with `getch()` and `ord()` in order to work with the (at least for me) gibberish that returns from `getch()`.

in my understanding `getch()` returns a byte stream, and ord does translate that byte data into unicode. and if iam not wrong there are keys like the arrow keys (this is my intention, to build a cmd "ui" to navigate) that are seperated into different unicode values.

so far, after trying myself and searching the web i come up with a soultion, provided by a person on the internet(information only for not claimig someone elses code as mine)

```
import msvcrt

while True:
    key = ord(msvcrt.getch())
    if key == 27: #ESC
        break
    elif key == 13: #Enter
        print("select")
    elif key == 224: #thing i do not understand
        key = ord(msvcrt.getch()) #thing i do not understand
        if key == 80: #Down arrow
            print("moveDown")
        elif key == 72: #Up arrow
            print("moveUp")
        elif key == 77: #Right arrow
            print("moveRight")
        elif key == 75: #Left arrow
            print("moveLeft")
```

this works fine, but the thing that i do not understand is, why it is necessary to make the second variable assignment. in my understanding `getch()` should return the value instantly, so i do not understand where the second `key = ord...` statement gets the data to assign it to the key variable.

I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: I don't think arrow keys have a unicode value.  The code you're using is working at a lower level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for [`msvcrt.getch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch):

> msvcrt.**getch()**
>
> Read a keypress and return the resulting character as a byte string.
> Nothing is echoed to the console. This call will block if a keypress
> is not already available, but will not wait for Enter to be pressed.
> **If the pressed key was a special function key, this will return `'\000'`
> or `'\xe0'`; the next call will return the keycode.** The `Control-C` keypress
> cannot be read with this function.

So, if a special function key (e.g. an arrow key) was pressed, we have to test for `0xE0` (224) and then read the next value.

Comment: ah ok, it seems i havent read the documentation properly, that explain this. thanks for the answer.